# what is usage of this method Runtime.getRuntime();

Tags: java, garbage-collection, runtime

I am new to java and facing a problem with this method `getRuntime();` which exists in `Runtime` class, what this method do? Does it affect Garbage Collection? and when we use it? I need somebody explain to me  briefly this method.

Comment: What part of the documentation don't you understand?

Comment: first does it effect on gc can we control in gc through this method ?then why and when we use it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call it when you want to use a method on `Runtime`  Many of these methods are duplicates in the `System` class which is simpler to call.

You should be able to assume a getter doesn't create new objects or cause garbage to be created (except perhaps the first time) otherwise its not a plain getter.

Answer (score 2):

You use it when you want to get a `Runtime` object back. It doesn't affect garbage collection at all and there isn't anything that special about it.

Most common two uses I've had to call it is when I want to get the number of available processors or add a shutdown hook.

If you want to control GC then you can fine tune it using the many [command line options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) you have available, without modifying your source. Trying to play around with the `Runtime` is not what you're looking for at all by the sounds of it.